# Enable to send data to servlet using AjAx and post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function validate (user_value){
    var name = user_value;
    $.ajax({
        url:"ggs.erm.servlet.setup5.AjaxS",
        data:{ namee :name},
        success:function(){
            alert("worked");
        }
    });
}
```

This is my Code. Is something wrong with it?? Any kind of syntax or semantics error. 
**Problem:**Not able to send parameter to servlet in URL.?????

Comment: url with `.` is it good.

Comment: Yes, actually I am working on localhost ,and thats how we access other JAVA files(ggs/erm/.....) in our project. It works fine.

Comment: so minko added an answer is that good?

Comment: @Jai I added type:"POST" ,as minko suggested ,but still the same problem.

Comment: just posted an answer checkout that if helps may be your function is in `doc ready` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your servlet's `doPost` method to handle the request you should add property `type` with value `post`.

```
function validate (user_value){
    var name = user_value;
    $.ajax({
        url:"ggs.erm.servlet.setup5.AjaxS",
        data:{ namee :name},
        type: 'post',
        success:function(){
            alert("worked");
        }
    });
}
```

This way your Ajax request will be post instead of get (the default one).

Comment: Although my sole purpose is send data using post,But I have written code to handle request both in GET and POST(In servlet). I am getting "no element found " ,I am using firebug. Any suggestion???

Comment: Also that URL looks weird. There's also the "Same Origin Policy" OP might want to read about.

Comment: @RishiPrakash : Is jQuery loaded? Otherwise "$" is undefined.

Comment: @Szocske Jquery is loaded.Getting alert "worked" .But data is not getting received on Servlet.

Comment: Solved!! Problem was with the as you suggested "POST",with jquery js which i included. And some minor semantic mistakes.

Comment: @Szocske is it right to fetch parameter as arguments:user_name , and pass them to data:{} field?????

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your function is in `doc ready` handler check this out and see if helps:

```
 function validate (user_value){
    var name = user_value;
    $.ajax({
       url:"ggs.erm.servlet.setup5.AjaxS",
       type:'POST', //<-----------------added this
       data:{ namee :name},
       success:function(data){
         if(data){
          alert("worked");
         }
       },
       error:function(){
         alert('not worked.');
       } 
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   // your other code stuff for calling the function
});
```